# php encode text before send method get url

Tags: php, search, methods, get

I use method get to send ex: Name: Pie; Age 28.
when click submit button
URL like `data.php?name=pie&age=28`.

but I don't like other see age, want to encode age (MD5).

to `data.php?name=pie&age=6F4922F45568161A8CDF4AD2299F6D23`

so how can i edit my code:

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="GET">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    age: <input type="text" name="<?php echo md5("age"); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should use for encode `base64_encode()` and for decode `base64_decode()`

Comment: You should use `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: @Bluetree he wants to encode the age.

Comment: md5 hashing is intended to be just one way, why would you want it encoded anyway?

Comment: @RobinSingh I suggest that he should change it to `POST` method. Why use `GET` method?

Comment: If the idea is to hide the value of the `age` field, I would suggest using `POST` method instead of `GET`. But if your choice is to go with `GET`, in order to send this value hashed, you may want to use client-side scripts before processing the form request.

Comment: @Bluetree yes he should use $_POST

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want others see your data it's better to use method Post instead of Get but if you persist on using hash to secure your code md5 is not recommended . check [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/openssl_encrypt) to encrypt and [openssl_decrypt](https://www.php.net/openssl_decrypt) to decrypt it.